# New Water Line for Dishwasher

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher

I’m trying to set up a dishwasher in my home for the first time. What is the best way to create a new water line?

Below my sink there is a PVC to metal connection and I’m not sure what the best attachment to create this new line is.

[image]

Comment: That's not actually PVC—it's CPVC.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to cut the hot line PVC and add a sharkbite tee connector with a 3/8" or 1/2" compression fitting, depending on what your dishwasher needs. See picture of tee below.  Then run a braided line to your washer.

[image]

https://www.walmart.com/ip/SharkBite-1-2-PTC-x-1-2-Compression-Brass-Tee-Stop/191815122

Answer (score 0):

Cut the PVC with something like a hacksaw a few inches below the existing valve and install a tee and a second valve. Nothing to it. You can use more SharkBite fittings if you like, or conventional compression fittings. Clean up the cut ends a bit for a good seal.

The valve's male connection should match your supply line's female connection. Take it with you to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Buy the [SharkBite removal tool](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-1-2-in-Fitting-Removal-Tool/1000182539?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-1000182539-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwzJmlBhBBEiwAEJyLu-aYPUcvpN9I36AWlxirXeB8t9mJyzroxJALvbwZz8qM6139r8Y7PxoCq3wQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  Turn the water off to your home. and remove the old shutoff. Replace it with a [sharkBite double shut off valve](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-Brass-1-2-in-Push-to-connect-x-3-8-in-Compression-Quarter-Turn/1001852490?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_208_Plumbing-Repair-_-1001852490-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwzJmlBhBBEiwAEJyLuzWXVZmf1H2IQCP60F28hnkotTi7d4kmgxeg9JAjTB31EPfUsHa_ZBoCrSIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Connect the lines to your DW and sink faucet.

Done. No cutting, splicing, gluing.